# erase rows and colums of a 2D vector, when a condition is achieved in another single vector?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a matrix (vector of vector), in other words, 2D vector (6 X 6) elements `<double>`, and after I have a vector with 6 elements `<int>`. the vector with ints has only "0" and "1". Then, I am looking for a way to remove a row and column of the 2D vector when a "0" is found in the vector (1D) of ints. This time is only 6 X 6 but later on, will be around 100 X 100.

What I've done is use iterators, and I successfully remove the rows but now I don't know how to tackle the columns.

This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {

    std::vector <int> boundaryConditions = { 0,1,1,1,0,0 };
    std::vector <std::vector<double>> matrix = { {1.46371e+07, 1.46371e+07, -1.46371e+07, -1.46371e+07, 0, 0},
    {1.46371e+07, 5.60371e+07, -1.46371e+07, -1.46371e+07, 0, -4.14e+07},
    {-1.46371e+07, -1.46371e+07, 5.60371e+07, 1.46371e+07, -4.14e+07, 0},
    {-1.46371e+07, -1.46371e+07, 1.46371e+07, 1.46371e+07, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, -4.14e+07, 0, 4.14e+07, 0},
    {0, -4.14e+07, 0, 0, 0, 4.14e+07}};

    int i = 0;
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = boundaryConditions.begin();
    while (it != boundaryConditions.end())
    {
        if (*it == 0)
        {
            it = boundaryConditions.erase(it);
            matrix.erase(matrix.begin() + i);
        }
        else
        {
            it++;
            i++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); j++)
        {
            std::cout << matrix[i][j] << std::setw(15);
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    system("pause>0");
}
```

Comment: A quick question -- why do you need to erase anything if you already have a vector indicating what rows are "on" and which are "off"?  Just use that int vector in your program to determine if a row/column is to be processed.

Comment: what would you like to do with columns?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, yes i taught about that, but i faced the situation on which i have to multiply the "reduced matrix" by a single vector with 3 elements in this case. the second thing is that ill use the library eigen library, for different calculations like inverse, transpose rotation and so on. But anyways i'll this idea, sounds pretty good, therefore, ill check it

Comment: @Keanyuan, with the "reduced matrix" ill perform transpose inverse and so on. Its much easier work with a matrix of 2 X 2 instead of 6 X 6 or even 100 X 100. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Why not create a new matrix as a result other than operating in place?

Comment: @Nimrod Yes thats another idea but i have to check it. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new matrix after you've removed the rows.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> removeColumns(const std::vector<int>& boundaryConditions, 
                                               const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& matrix)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> returnValue(matrix.size());
    size_t curRow = 0;
    size_t curCol = 0;
    for (auto& v : returnValue)
    {
        for (size_t curCol = 0; curCol < matrix[0].size(); ++curCol)
        {
              if (boundaryConditions[curCol] == 1)
                  v.push_back(matrix[curRow][curCol]);
        }
        ++curRow;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Then you would call it like this, given that you have already removed the rows from `matrix`:

```
matrix = removeColumns({0,1,1,1,0,0}, matrix);
```

Here is a [Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63f676eb70713b67).

---

If you want an in-place solution, here is an example:

```
void removeColumns(const std::vector<int>& boundaryConditions, std::vector<std::vector<double>>& matrix)
{
    size_t curCol = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < boundaryConditions.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (boundaryConditions[i] == 0)
        {
            for (auto& v : matrix)
               v.erase(v.begin() + curCol);
        }
        else
          ++curCol;
    }            
}
```

Then it would be called like this:

```
removeColumns({0,1,1,1,0,0}, matrix);
```

Here is a [Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fbcdf44690f2d71)

---

Another solution, if feasible for you, is to mark each entry to erase with a value, maybe `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`.  Then in a second pass, use `erase/remove` idiom, thus reducing the number of `erase` calls needed.

Here is an example:

```
void removeColumns(const std::vector<int>& boundaryConditions,
                   std::vector<std::vector<double>>& matrix)
{
    // Mark the entries to delete
    for (size_t i = 0; i < boundaryConditions.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (boundaryConditions[i] == 0)
            std::for_each(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(),[&](std::vector<double>& vect) 
             { vect[i] = std::numeric_limits<double>::max(); });
    }            

    // One pass through the matrix to remove the marked entries.
    for (auto& v : matrix)
        v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), std::numeric_limits<double>::max()), v.end());
}
```

Here is a [Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66436cf0f65ab463)

Note that `std::remove` doesn't really remove anything, thus doesn't incur the penalty of an actual `erase`.

The single `erase` call erases an entire range, not just single values, thus has the potential to be faster than the first in-place solution given (but you have to time them, I can't guarantee which is faster).

Comment: Thanks i tested it and now everything works. Just for curiosity, using erase or push_back slows down my code? i am talking about performance. because i saw that both generate copies, therefore, if i have a 100 X 100 elements so many copies will be generated right?. FOR NOW EVERYTHING WORKS, but later one i'll have to check the performance.

Comment: inplace solution with `erase` may be slow since you are repeatedly moving the same elements backward. `push_back()` can be sped up by calling `.reserve()` upfront.

Comment: I know it could be slow.  Another speed up is to mark the entries to erase in one pass, and then in a second pass through each subvector, use `erase/remove` idiom.

Comment: @baezacaljo Honestly 100x100 in this day and age of computers is hardly anything, maybe almost nothing.  If you are talking about multiple thousands of rows and columns, then that is a different story.  Second, compiler optimizations may eliminate the copies being made (RVO, NRVO, etc.)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for your answer, i just gave an example of 100 X 100 but yes you are right i need 1000 X 1000, which i am pretty sure ill get into those, however as Eugene said i used reserve() and also i heard about emplace_back(). Everything you are telling me right now is helping me a lot. Now i see the impact of writing a clean code and the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help, not fully tested:
Let A be the binaryConditions array,

```
void reduce(std::vector<int> A, std::vector<int> &target) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int nOnes = 0;
    while (i<A.size() && j < A.size()) {
        if (A[i] != 0) {
            ++i;
            nOnes++;
        }
        else {
            j = max(i + 1, j);
            while (j < A.size() && A[j] == 0) ++j;
            if (j >= A.size()) break;
            swap(A[i], A[j]);
            swap(target[i], target[j]);
        }
    }
    A.resize(nOnes);
    target.resize(nOnes);
}
```